# Calling Google Play Downloader Library out of an Activity

Tags: apk-expansion-files

I'm trying to use APK expansion files in my app that uses the MVP pattern.
Therefore I put the code for calling the Google Play Downloader Library (GPDL) methods from the [APK Expansion Files article](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) not in an `Activity` but in a specialized facade class (`XapkDownloader`).
It has the method `startDownload` and the methods to add listeners for `onDownloadStateChanged` and `onDownloadProgress`.
`XapkDownloader` has also the implementation of `IDownloaderClient` as an inner class.

The UI for displaying the download progress is a `Fragment` and its presenter calls `XapkDownloader.startDownload`.
There the call to `DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired` returns DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED (that's fine).
Then the calls to `DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub` and `stub.connect` run fine (no exceptions).
However, none of the methods of the `IDownloaderClient` implementation are called and I don't see any error in the log.

I suspect that I should create the `PendingIntent` to pass into `DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired` not using `PendingIntent.getActivity` but in a diffrent way.

Maybe someone can suggest an example of calling GPDL not from an Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's ok to put the code to call GPDL into any class.
My mistake was the wrong declaration of the downloader service in AndroidManifest.xml. My implementation of it is in a "sub-package" and the declaration did not reflect it.

Comment: Could you please tell me that is it possible to keep library (jar/aar) as an expansion file. If so then how can i add that as dependency in gradle and declare its activity in manifest?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a ready answer for you. I used the expansion APK for storing data only.